# Flutter Deserialize a JSON and save it locally

Tags: flutter, dart

On the following code, is how i am fetching and saving the Json localy.
On the console i can see the Json as follows.
{"cyclus":29,"range":50,"force":-15.25071}

I can decode the data, and check for the key if it exists or not.
But right now i do not know how to call the values of the key´s and display the values

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

const String fileName = 'myJsonPotyFile.json';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: WebSocketPOTY(),
    );
  }
}

//apply this class on home: attribute at MaterialApp()
class WebSocketPOTY extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebSocketPOTY({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _WebSocketDHT();
  }
}

class _WebSocketDHT extends State<WebSocketPOTY> {
  late String potenty1;
  late String potenty2;

  late IOWebSocketChannel channel;
  late bool connected; //boolean value to track if WebSocket is connected

  late File _filePath;

  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/$fileName');
  }

  void _readJson() async {
    _filePath = await _localFile;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _readJson();
    connected = false; //initially connection status is "NO" so its FALSE

    potenty1 = "0";
    potenty2 = "0";

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      channelconnect();
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  channelconnect() {
    try {
      channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://192.168.0.254:80");
      channel.stream.listen(
        (message) {
          print(message);
          Map<String, dynamic> jsondat = json.decode(message);
          String data = json.encode(jsondat);
          _filePath.writeAsString(data);
          setState(() {
            if (jsondat.containsKey('cyclus')) {
              connected = true;
            } else if (jsondat.containsKey('range')) {
              setState(() {
                potenty1 = jsondat['force'];
                potenty2 = jsondat['range'];
                //_filePath.writeAsString(message);
              });
            }
          });
        },
        onDone: () {
          //if WebSocket is disconnected
          print("Web socket is closed");
          setState(() {
            connected = false;
          });
        },
        onError: (error) {
          print(error.toString());
        },
      );
    } catch (_) {
      print("error on connecting to websocket.");
    }
  }

  Future<void> sendcmd(String cmd) async {
    if (connected == true) {
      channel.sink.add(cmd); //sending Command to NodeMCU
      //send command to NodeMCU
    } else {
      channelconnect();
      print("Websocket is not connected.");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Poty"),
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 89, 106)),
      body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter, //inner widget alignment to center
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  //showing if websocket is connected or disconnected
                  child: connected
                      ? const Text(
                          "WEBSOCKET: CONNECTED",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        )
                      : const Text(
                          "DISCONNECTED",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        )),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              Text(
                "Poty1 Value $potenty1 Milimeter",
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Text(
                "Poty2 Value $potenty2 Newton",
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html 
It shows you how to deal with JSON that is in array format using indexing. Though in your case, you may want to just loop through each element in data[0].

Comment: @TrayDenney ,  thanks for the help. I was reading your suggestion but i do not know how to implement it. Flutter is some New Land for me and even more Json. I edit my question and posted my approach. But unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert **jsonData** of type **Map<String, dynamic>** to a **String** using:

String data = json.encode(jsondata);

Now, you can store this **data** string locally. You can use **Shared Preferences** or **Get Storage** for local storage. 
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences 
https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage

For getting data, again you can use 
json.decode(data); 
**data** is the string that you will read from local storage.

Comment: thanks for the help. I was reading your suggestion but i do not know how to implement it. Flutter is some New Land for me and even more Json. I edit my question and posted my approach. But unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: You can follow some tutorial to save String locally. I told you the way to encode json data to String so that it can be stored in local storage.

Comment: the problem that i have is not to store the file. Storing the file i know how to do it.  The problem that i have is how to fetch it when the Json comes like this {"cyclus":9,"range":[3,12,23,29,31,50],"force":[1,3,15,23,48,50]}.  Im trying to fetch it doing  ...... else if (message.substring(0, 6) == "cyclus") .... and i think here i am doing something wrong

Comment: Don't check for message, decode the data Map<String, dynamic> jsondata = json.decode(message);  and then you can check for key if it exists or not. jsonData.containsKey('cyclus'); it will return true if key exists else false.

Comment: Hello Waqar..... First of all thanks a lot for your help until now. I came a step closer. Like you sugested i decode the Json and checked for the key. And it is working. Only right now i do not know how to call and display the values inside the key´s. Please help. I edit my post and put the code that i have until now.Thanks in advance

Comment: That's great :)

Comment: If you can please continu giving me some help

Comment: Means I didn't get you can you explain further please. I think you are already getting the values inside key. You can read the value of key using jsondat['key_here'];

Comment: Take a look on the first post. I edit it and put the recent code. I can call the key for example : if (jsondat.containsKey('cyclus')) {
              connected = true... But right now with your suggested approach I do not know how to give for the variable potenty2 the values that I can setState and display it

Comment: No i am not able to read the  value of key using  potenty1 = jsondat['range'];  or  potenty2 = jsondat['force'];  and after displaying it

Comment: Can you show output of jsondat by printing it.

Comment: print(jsondat); ..... I get this..... flutter: {cyclus: 9, range: 16.32162666, force: 21.02349663}

Comment: If i print the values. I get the correct values. if (jsondat.containsKey("cyclus")) { connected = true; print(jsondat["range"]); print(jsondat["force"]); //range = jsondat["range"]; //force = jsondat["force"]; }

Comment: I think the problem right now lies here.                  potenty1 = jsondat['force'];
                potenty2 = jsondat['range'];

Comment: Can you show the error/issue? Also, please make sure that the datatype of range and force are String because you are assigning them in String variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244680/discussion-between-waqar-ali-siyal-and-carlos-costa).

Comment: "Also, please make sure that the datatype of range and force are String because you are assigning them in String variables."  I was not declaring properly range and force on the ESP32 side. Right now it is a String That was the cause. Thank you very very much for your help. It is working. THANKS